# Парсинг ссылок на страницы сайта, как собрать все ссылки

Tags: php, html, css, link

Есть такой быдло корявый код:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input style="display: inline;" type='text' name='pole1' value='1'>
    <p><input style="cursor:pointer;display: inline;" type="submit" name="button_id" value="OK" /></p>
</form>
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
# Если кнопка нажата
        $data = $_POST['pole1'];
$html = file_get_html($data);

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) //Находим все линки 
       echo $element->href . '<br>'; //выводим их на экран  
?>
```

1. Вопрос как с помощью него найти все ссылки на сайте, чтобы от главной парсились и уровни вложености например 2-3й пока не найдет все страници сайта ?
2.Вопрос как исправить ошибки вида

```
Notice: Undefined index: pole1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\index.php on line 8

Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\index.php on line 11
```

Сам код всеравно выполняется если в вести урл в форму..

Comment: Есть идеи  как это реализовать ?

Comment: Регулярные выражения, все ссылки имеют вид <a href=" LINK ">

Comment: Так они и так сейчас грабятся со траници вопрос как сделатть это цикличным если обошел 1 страницу перешел на другую и тд пока не просканит все страници сайта и не соберет все урлы сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Я знаю, как с этим бороться:

```
if($_POST['button_id'] == true) {
  $data = $_POST['pole1'];
$html = file_get_html($data);

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) //Находим все линки 
       echo $element->href . '<br>'; //выводим их на экран  
}

$_POST['button_id'] = false;
```

То есть, если кнопка нажата, то выполняется код. Но если мы в конце не поставим `button_id` значение false после выполнения кода, то всегда будет TRUE. 
Простыми словами, мы вырубаемся после того, как код отработает.